# Compare content of input with content of div on click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I got the following problem:

I got a shop in which i want to allow the user to buy some articles just 8 times for example. I made a column in my databse called "gm_max_order" which contains the maximal amount of how much which product can be buyed. And i also managed to get it to work that the article can´t get added to shopping cart when you type in a number `> gm_max_order`.

Now the problem is, if gm_max_order is 8 for example, i can't add 9 to my shopping cart, but i can add 2x7. I need to know how i can compare the input field (in which people select the amount of how much they want to buy) with the shopping cart content on click on the `"AddToCart"` Button.

This is my input and my cart button:

```
    {if $module_data.QTY_DATA.VALUE != 1 || (($GM_SHOW_QTY == '1' && $module_data.GM_ATTRIBUTES) || ($GM_SHOW_QTY == '1' && $module_data.GM_HAS_ATTRIBUTES == '0'))}
            <span class="quantity_container">
            {if $module_data.UNIT}<label for="{$module_data.QTY_DATA.ID}" class="products_quantity_unit">{$module_data.UNIT}</label>{/if}
            <input type="{$module_data.QTY_DATA.TYPE}" name="{$module_data.QTY_DATA.NAME}" id="{$module_data.QTY_DATA.ID}" class="article-count-input numeric input-text products_quantity {$module_data.QTY_DATA.CLASS}" value="{$module_data.QTY_DATA.VALUE}" />
</span>
 {else}
<input type="hidden" name="{$HIDDEN_QTY_NAME}" value="{$module_data.QTY_DATA.VALUE}" />
{/if}
```

and this is the addtocart button:

```
<a href="{$module_data.GM_PRODUCTS_BUTTON_BUY_NOW_URL}" class="addcart button_green button_set action_add_to_cart"{if $module_data.PRODUCTS_NAME != ''} title="{$module_data.PRODUCTS_NAME|replace:'"':'&quot;'} {$txt.text_buy}"{/if}
 onclick="return checkAddToCart(event, '{$module_data.QTY_DATA.ID}', {$product_stock}, {$product_max_order});">
```

The Shopping Cart is just some DIV.

Comment: What kind of framework are you using?

Comment: Sadly I have to use Gambio, a german shopsystem. It is working, as you can see above, with Smarty Tags.

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions. I think the best way is a mix of session + ajax. Save your cart into the session as an array, an object or whatever you prefer. When a new article is added make an ajax call to a specific controller that checks the session and returns back a json response. I don't know what framework you're using, but i don't think it would be difficult to create a controller like this.